# MSBuild Exec - All commands exit with MSB3073, exit code 0xC0000005

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, environment, access-violation

Windows 10 64-bit - Visual Studio Community 2017

Brand new Hello World C# project.

I added the following to my build tasks:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
  <Message Text="Testing" Importance="high"></Message>
  <Exec Command="echo Test" />
</Target>
```

I see the "Testing" `Message` executed by the build, so I know the `Target` is running, at least.

The next task, `Exec`, always shows the following no matter what commands I give it.

```
1>$(ProjectPath)(60,5): error MSB3073: The command "echo Test" exited with code -1073741819.
```

-1073741819 is of course 0xC0000005, Access Violation.

- Note: The exact same thing happens if I don't use a `Target` but instead use post-build commands from the Project Properties GUI (It uses Exec to run those internally, anyway).
- Note: I've had similar issues with VS Code somehow misusing my ComSpec variable, which for reference is defined as `ComSpec` : `%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe`

Comment: Have you try to run Visual Studio as administrator? How about run the command `echo Test` with command prompt? It seems to be related to your environment, have you try to update your system to latest version?

Comment: Running as Administrator gives same results, and `echo Test` works fine in a typical command prompt. I also just updated Visual Studio, and tend to keep my Win10 updated whenever it alerts me.

Comment: @Omniscience, Have you tried to reset settings for Visual Studio(Back up if need)? Tools->Import and Export Settings->Reset all settings. Or try to reinstall Visual Studio, check if it works fine.